# @CreatedBy @LastModifiedBy annotations are not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When ever I create a any user that needs to be taken automatically who has created the User with the @CreatedBy annotation and when I manupulate any thing thats needs to be taken automatically with the annotation @LastModifiedBy. But this is not working now. What may be the reason?

```
This is my entity class

@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by" , nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false) 
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
    @Transient
    public <T> T getView(Class<T> viewClass) {
        try {
            T view = viewClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, view);
            return view;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error("Error mapping model to view", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: you need to create a custom class that implements `AuditorAware<String>`  and define its `getCurrentAuditor()`

Comment: To add to @One guy's answer. It depends on where you are getting your User From. Example from Principal

Comment: Did you find the solution in the end?

Answer (score 10):

Add below annotation to your Application Class.

```
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
```

Define the bean:

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware(){
    return new CustomAuditAware();
}
```

Create CustomAuditAware class:

```
public class CustomAuditAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        return null;
    }

    return ((User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
}
```

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-two/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your custom class that implements `AuditorAware<?>` in order to define which is your current auditor. So let's define by following code:

```
public class AuditingService implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of("Bhargav");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add @EnableJpaAuditing annotation into to main class and define a bean for your custom implementation as well

Answer (score 0):

Add this Bean to your Main Application

```
@Bean
    AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
    // override getCurrentAuditor method to provide the current user
    return () -> Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        }
```